# can't initialize a new rails application within the directory of another

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, aptana

I am learning Rails and I am using Aptana studio for that. It was working fine before now when I try to create a new project It is giving me error "can't initialize a new rails application within the directory of another"

I uninstalled railinstaller and Aptana Studio then now trying to re create a new application it is giving me this error. I am struck now, please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem myself, I was not able to create a new project anywhere on my PC, Finally after spending a day and night I figured out the problem. I had created a project inside User which was not letting me create new project any where in my drive (all).

Thanks for the solution that other have provided,