# Can not create rails apps anymore under Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I have a problem with all my three! Ubuntu systems. I can't create any Rails projects anymore with the following command

```
rails new abcde
```

I get the following error message.

```
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first
```

I know the error message is really clear, I googled and checked all the entries here on StackOverflow. No one had another explanation other than there is a project in a parent folder, which is not the case in my systems!

I checked all folders back to root for any hidden files resembling a rails project. Nothing! I even created a new folder under root /projects and tried to create a project in there, same error. I don't know what to do anymore, I have the same problem on all three of my Ubuntu computers. Has anyone ever had this problem and could fix it? What could be another cause of this. Because there is no project in any of parent folders.

The only possible solution for me is, that there is maybe a PATH variable for Rails that I don't know about and there is maybe a project in there?

Comment: maybe `rails` command is wrapped with some sort of alias?

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTIONS:

0) I'm assuming you're typing these commands from a console window, and not executing a shell script, shortcut, or "something else".  Correct?

1) Please update your post with the following: `ruby -v`; `rails -v` (Ruby and Rails version info)

2) Please try another test project, and copy/paste any error or warning messages you see:

```
cd /tmp
rails new abc -f 
  <= another test "rails new", with "--force" option
```

3) Assuming you've installed RVM, and assuming your "rails new" is calling "run bundle install", then also make sure your user is a member of the "rvm" group:

- `sudo usermod -G rvm -a MYUSER`

4) If you haven't already, please also look at these links:

- [can't initialize a new rails application within the directory of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285389/cant-initialize-a-new-rails-application-within-the-directory-of-another)
- [Problems with RVM and Rails when creating new app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104338/problems-with-rvm-and-rails-when-creating-new-app)